# Magento 2 overwrite html file in custom module

Tags: module, knockoutjs, magento2.2.2

I would like to overwrite the following file `row_incl_tax.html` in my custom module:

`vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax.html`

`app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax.html`

I've tried:

`app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`:

`var config= {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_weee/template/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax.html': 'Custom_Module/template/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax.html',
        }
    }
}`

But the above isn't working for me. Any idea is this the correct way?

Comment: Sorted! I was missing the **web** folder should be like: `app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the **web/template** directory in your path.

the **row_incl_tax.html** file should be in the below path of your module.

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax.html